# How to format bibliography in table of contents as part instead of chapter with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, formatting, scrbook

I'm writing a thesis in the `scrbook`-class which will have an appendix after the main part followed by the bibliography. In the table of contents, the entry for the bibliography is formatted the same way as the other chapters which makes it look like a part of the appendix, which is it not.

So I would like to format the entry **Bibliography** the same way as **Appendix** (larger font and some spacing to the chapters of the appendix).

The image below shows the `TOC` generated by the example which is basically it's look so far.

[image: TOC example]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries\rmfamily}

% bibliography entry
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{dummy22,
        author  = {C. Dummy},
        title   = {How to cite},
        journal = {Citing for dummies},
        year    = {2022},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

% bibliography settings
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% list of symbols
\usepackage[automake, nonumberlist, nogroupskip, symbols]{glossaries-extra}
    \makeglossaries
    \glsxtrnewsymbol[description={The letter A.}]{letterA}{A}


% Main document
\begin{document}

% TOC + Symbols
\pagenumbering{Roman}   
    \tableofcontents 
    \printunsrtglossary[title=Symbols,type=symbols]
    \clearpage

% Content of document
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Literature Review}
    \chapter{Theory}
        \section{Theory of Something}
        \section{Other Theories}
    \chapter{Experiment}
        \section{Calibration}
        \section{Measurement 1}
        \section{Measurement 2}
    \chapter{Summary}

\appendix
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
    \chapter{Some Code}
    \chapter{Numerical Parameters}
    
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MWE the appendix is defined to appear in the table of contents as Part while the bibliography is defined as a chapter.   `biblatex` offers the facility to specify how bib headings appear (in various parts of the documents, and other parameters as well).  Thus the solution is to use

```
\defbibheading{bibintoc}{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bibname}}
```

to achieve the desired result (and see Section 3.7.7 of the biblatex manual for the full specifications, `texdoc biblatex`).[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. This was the kind of solution I was hoping for. (I was expecting there should be such a solution but I wasn't able to find the correct settings)

Comment: Actually, I had to add a few more adjustments to:
 1. make it work correctly with `hyperref`, 
 2. keep the heading before the references,
 3. add the `\bibname` to the running title. 

Final result:  
`\defbibheading{bibintoc}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bibname}\chapter*{\bibname}\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}`

Answer (score 1):

Only small changes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries\rmfamily}

% bibliography entry
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{dummy22,
        author  = {C. Dummy},
        title   = {How to cite},
        journal = {Citing for dummies},
        year    = {2022},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

% bibliography settings
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% list of symbols
\usepackage[automake, nonumberlist, nogroupskip, symbols]{glossaries-extra}
    \makeglossaries
    \glsxtrnewsymbol[description={The letter A.}]{letterA}{A}


% Main document
\begin{document}

% TOC + Symbols
\pagenumbering{Roman}   
    \tableofcontents 
    \printunsrtglossary[title=Symbols,type=symbols]
    \clearpage

% Content of document
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Literature Review}
    \chapter{Theory}
        \section{Theory of Something}
        \section{Other Theories}
    \chapter{Experiment}
        \section{Calibration}
        \section{Measurement 1}
        \section{Measurement 2}
    \chapter{Summary}
   \chapter{Bibliography}
    \nocite{*}
   \printbibliography[heading=none] 
    

\appendix
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
    \chapter{Some Code}
    \chapter{Numerical Parameters}      

\end{document}
```

[image: one]

[image: two]

or if you want  the Bibliography at the end,  with fonts like `part` use

```
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bibname}        
     \chapter*{\huge \bibname}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
```

`\cleardoublepage` is needed to make the Bibliography appear in page #15 in the TOC. Otherwise it will show page 13 instead.

[image: final]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I certainly works but feels a bit hacky.